# How to customize the push Received from onesignal.com?

Tags: android, onesignal

I USE THES SORCE for get and show notfication but this coode not customize . i need sorce for customized notfication Received from onesignal.com

i need send url by onesignal and Received  and show for icon notfication
i need send title by onesignal and set title
i need send diccription by onesignal and set diccription 
i need send url and set uri
tanks for help

```
package booke.vfj.angour.ir.baftani_davood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class G extends Application {

    public static Context               context;
    public static LayoutInflater        inflater;
    public static Activity              currentActivity;
    public static ArrayList<StructTest> Recordsfehrset = new ArrayList<StructTest>();
    public static ArrayList<StructTest2> recordjoziat = new ArrayList<StructTest2>();
    public static ArrayList<StructTest> fov = new ArrayList<StructTest>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler()).init();
    }

    private class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
            try {
                String messageTitle;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;

                if (additionalData != null) {
                    if (additionalData.has("discount"))
                        messageTitle = "Discount!";
                    else if (additionalData.has("bonusCredits"))
                        messageTitle = "Bonus Credits!";
                    else
                        messageTitle = "Other Extra Data";

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTitle(messageTitle).setMessage(message + "\n\n" + additionalData.toString());
                }
                else if (isActive) // If a push notification is received when the app is being used it does not display in the notification bar so display in the app.
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("OneSignal Message")
                            .setMessage(message);

                // Add your app logic around this so the user is not interrupted during gameplay.
                if (builder != null)
                    builder.setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",null)
                            .create().show();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The OneSignal SDK will take care of setting the title, icon, and opening URLs when the notification is tapped on.

By default OneSignal will only show a notification in the Notification Area on Android when your app is not in focus. If your app is in focus the NotificationOpenedHandler will be called instead of showing a notification. If you rather always show a notification you can call `OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);` after init.

Also you can remove `OneSignal.startInit(this).init();` as the line below it is also initializing OneSignal.

Comment: i nees sample coode or project . plese